# How do I completely stop the execution of a JavaScript setInterval? I've tried clearInterval, and that does not work

Tags: javascript, setinterval

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!**

I have a piece of JavaScript with what I call a "nested" `setInterval`; one `setInterval` that calls a function with another `setInterval`.

What i want is when the "outer" `setInterval` calls the function when the "inner" `setInterval` is already running, I want the "inner" `setInterval` to stop it's original interval and start again fresh.

So:

1. Outer `setInterval` fires.
2. Outer `setInterval` calls function with inner `setInterval`.
3. Inner `setInterval` fires.

... inner runs for a while

4. Outer `setInterval` fires ... again.
5. Outer `setInterval` calls inner `setInterval` ... again
6. Inner `setInterval` stops it's original run.
7. Inner `setInterval` starts a fresh, new run.

See my example below:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <style type="text/css">
                div {
                    margin: 100px 100px;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    
                let alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
    
                function start(){
                    var the_button = document.getElementById('the_button');
                    the_button.addEventListener('click', testFunction);
                }
    
                function testFunction(){
                    console.log("Starting ...");
                    if(myIntervalVal) clearInterval(myIntervalVal);
                    var myIntervalVal = setInterval(printAlphabet, 10000);
                }
    
                function printAlphabet(){
                    var i = 0;
                    console.log(alphabet[i]);
                    if(mySubInterval) clearInterval(mySubInterval);
                    var mySubInterval = setInterval(function(){
                        i++;
                        if(i === alphabet.length) i = 0;
                        console.log(alphabet[i]);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="start();"><div><button type="button" id="the_button">click me</button></div></body>
    </html>
```

The way I feel this should work is:

```
outer fires
    inner prints
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
outer is fired again
    inner stops printing
    inner prints
    A
    B
    C
    D
    E
    F
    ...
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: `var myIntervalVal` makes it local to that block. The variable does not persist over multiple invocations. Declare it outside the block instead, so that it's persistent and can be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

It would work, but you need to lift the `mySubInterval` out of the `printAlphabet` function.

```js
var mySubInterval;
function printAlphabet(){
  var i = 0;
  console.log(alphabet[i]);
  if(mySubInterval) clearInterval(mySubInterval);
  mySubInterval = setInterval(function(){
    // …
```

Same rule applies to `myInterval` and `testFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

While the other solution works, You dont' need to do that; you should only need to move `if(mySubInterval) clearInterval(mySubInterval);` to the bottom of the `printAlphabet()` function. Before, you were checking if mySubInterval was truthy before it was declared, but now your browser "knows" that it's truthy and will do the `clearInterval()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .div {
                margin: 100px 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            let alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

            function start(){
                var the_button = document.getElementById('the_button');
                the_button.addEventListener('click', testFunction);
            }

            function testFunction(){
                console.log("Starting ...");
                if(myIntervalVal) clearInterval(myIntervalVal);
                var myIntervalVal = setInterval(printAlphabet, 10000);
            }

            function printAlphabet(){
                var i = 0;
                console.log(alphabet[i]);
                var mySubInterval = setInterval(function(){
                    i++;
                    if(i === alphabet.length) i = 0;
                    console.log(alphabet[i]);
                }, 1000);
                if(mySubInterval) clearInterval(mySubInterval);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="start();"><div class="div"><button type="button" id="the_button">click me</button></div></body>
</html>
```